# Firebase: "The constructor Message(String, String) is undefined

Tags: java, android, eclipse, firebase

I am trying to learn a bit of Firebase in order to make a simple database to work with in a student project. Now I've come across a problem that Ive spent hours and hours on and still dont seem to figure out.

I have used a simple example from firebase: to write list data and to read list data: https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html

So Ive pasted the examples, modified the code to match my own data base. But eclipse keeps complaining on the constructor of this line: newPushRef.setValue(new Message("wilma", "Hello"));
Error says: The constructor Message(String, String) is undefined. It wants to import "android.os.Message;" I dont know if I should, but anyhow nothing seems to solve it. The suggestion says the constructor should be empty.
What am I missing here?

I have imported the the latest Java SDK to the libs folder, clicked "Build path".
Same with the Simple-login library.

I am new to java, please be humble.

edit:
Its the same issue further down with the "System.out.println(m.getUser_id());"
"The method getUser_id() is undefined for the type Message"

This is my StartActivity:

```
package com.mah.phli_xjobb_textpushmess_25mars;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.Query;
import com.firebase.simplelogin.SimpleLogin;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);



    //---FIREBASE--//
    // First we get a reference to the location of the user's name data:
    Firebase listRef = new Firebase("https://listtest.firebaseio.com/message_list");

    // Generate a reference to a new location with push()
    Firebase newPushRef = listRef.push();

    // Set some data to the generated location
    newPushRef.setValue(new Message("wilma", "Hello"));

    // Get the name generated by push
    String pushedName = newPushRef.getName();



    listRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Message m = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            System.out.println(m.getUser_id());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });





    //---END FIREBASE----//



    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}//End class
```

Comment: This seems likely to be an Eclipse configuration issue. I've added the tag; hope someone helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Message` class in the example code in the docs is actually not a real class that's shipped with the SDK, it's there for demonstration purposes. It is meant as a stand-in for your own class that you implement and wish to save in Firebase.

Your class will need to the couple of constraints here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Firebase.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)

An actual implementation of `Message` might look something like this:

```
class Message {
    public String name;
    public String text;

    public Message(String name, String text) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
    }

    // Due to the constraints in the above link, the class must have a 
    // default constructor
    private Message() {}

}
```

Then, you can add whatever functionality you need to your own `Message` class. Also, be sure to remove the import for the `android.os.Message`!

Comment: Totally got it now! Thanks Greg!